# Why does my JavaScript console always says undefined

Tags: javascript

This piece of code should send a message in WhatsApp Web, on entering it to the JavaScript console, but it always says `undefined`.

How can I prevent this?

```
function whatsAppText(t) {
  window.InputEvent = window.Event || window.InputEvent;
  var d = new Date();
  var event = new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true});
  var textbox = document.querySelector('#main > footer > div.block-compose > div.input-container > div > div.input');
  textbox.textContent = t;
  textbox.dispatchEvent(event);
  document.querySelector('.icon.btn-icon.icon-send.send-container').click()
}
```

Comment: Where does it say undefined?  I don't see where you're writing anything to the console.

Comment: You are not using `console.log()` anywhere in code

Comment: @Amy it's the output after pressing enter.

Comment: Not sure where it returns undefined, but you might want to `return` something with your function.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Where is anything being written to the console?  How are you calling this method?

Comment: you mean, when you create it? It's ok, just return value, the output of execution. You can get this function by name `whatsAppText` later in console

Comment: @Amy I am calling this methode just by entering it in the console. Or do I have to run something like "whatsAppText(t);"

Comment: @Bäume sindgrün When you call a function in console it always prints the `return` value of the `function`. As here not value is returned so by default `undefined` is returned

Comment: You are *not* calling it by entering it into the console. By entering it into the console, you *define* it, and then you must call it using `whatsAppText(t)`. But be warned: you are not returning anything from your function, so when you call it, the code will run and it will send a message in WhatsApp, but it will *also* say `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 2):

The console will report the ***returned*** value of an expression. If a function does something meaningful, but does not return anything, then executing the function returns nothing, hence `undefined`.

Here is an example:

```js
function foo(){
  document.body.innerHTML = "<p>I did some work, but I didn't return a value.</p>";
}

console.log(foo());  // undefined
```

As opposed to:

```js
function foo(){
  return "I did some work, and I did return a value.";
}

console.log(foo());  // "I did some work, and I did return a value."
```

But, if all you are doing is entering the function into your console and not even calling it, that won't return anything and the console will report `undefined`. Based on the code you've shown, even if you then invoke your function with, say:  `whatsAppText("test")`, ***your function will execute*** and send the message, but you don't have your function set up to ***return*** anything, so ***you'll still see*** `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are only defining a function and not executing it. You have to call the function somewhere after it's been declared:

```
whatsAppText('This should work!');
```

Comment: This will still report `undefined` in the console because the function doesn't produce a value.

Comment: True. I should have explained better what I'm trying to address with this answer, which is the actual problem of the user not understanding why the code he posted isn't doing what he expected. Given that this function is not meant to return anything (only producing side-effects) then its actual return value becomes irrelevant in this context, I would say.